# Events not firing on jw player when it is in full screen

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I am trying to use JW player. We have timer events(javascript) on it. Events are firing when player is in default size but when it is in full screen mode events are not firing.

I would appreciate if someone can help us.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please could you provide a sample of the code for the events that you are attaching, or at least the types of events that you are watching. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a link to where you are running this.

Comment: Actually I am putting html elements over top of video. they are rendered at particular time and video is paused. But for full screen mode video is paused but no html elements are visible. I have also tried putting zindex to max value too.But still no results.Please help.

Comment: You need to provide a link. People on SO will not be able to help without this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe JW Player has a function `.setFullscreen(false)`, which you can use to take the player out of fullscreen. You'll probably have to do this to get any HTML elements above the player to appear.